# Consulta SQL que compara duas tabelas e retornar valores

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, comparação

Trabalho com uma base de dados usando com SGBD o PostgreSQL, onde preciso comparar tabelas, exemplo: tabela_janeiro e tabela_fevereiro.

*Preciso realizar duas consultas...*

**1º** Deve retornar o valores que contem na tabela_janeiro e não contem na tabela_fevereiro.

**2º** Deve retornar o valores que contem na tabela_fevereiro e não contem na tabela_janeiro. (Tipo o inverso kkk)

Desde ja agradeço a ajuda !

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que sua estrutura de dados seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_janeiro
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    txt TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( id )
);

CREATE TABLE tb_fevereiro
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    txt TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( id )
);
```

Contendo os seguintes registros:

```
-- INSERE REGISTROS EM JANEIRO
INSERT INTO tb_janeiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 1, 'ALPHA' );
INSERT INTO tb_janeiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 2, 'BETA' );
INSERT INTO tb_janeiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 3, 'GAMMA' );
INSERT INTO tb_janeiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 4, 'DELTA' );
INSERT INTO tb_janeiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 5, 'EPISILON' );

-- INSERE REGISTROS EM FEVEREIRO
INSERT INTO tb_fevereiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 1, 'ALPHA' );
INSERT INTO tb_fevereiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 2, 'BETA' );
INSERT INTO tb_fevereiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 3, 'GAMMA' );
INSERT INTO tb_fevereiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 4, 'SIGMA' );
INSERT INTO tb_fevereiro ( id, txt ) VALUES ( 5, 'OMEGA' );
```

Você pode usar um `LEFT JOIN` com uma condição na cláusula `WHERE` testando se o registro não existe na outra tabela, por exemplo:

```
-- RECUPERA REGISTROS CONTIDOS EM JANEIRO QUE NÃO ESTAO CONTIDOS NA EM FEVEREIRO
SELECT
    jan.id,
    jan.txt
FROM
    tb_janeiro AS jan
LEFT JOIN
    tb_fevereiro AS fev ON ( jan.txt = fev.txt )
WHERE
    fev.id IS NULL;
```

Saída:

```
| id |      txt |
|----|----------|
|  4 |    DELTA |
|  5 | EPISILON |
```

A mesma consulta pode ser usada para fazer o inverso:

```
-- RECUPERA REGISTROS CONTIDOS EM FEVEREIRO QUE NÃO ESTAO CONTIDOS NA EM JANEIRO
SELECT
    fev.id,
    fev.txt
FROM
    tb_fevereiro AS fev
LEFT JOIN
    tb_janeiro AS jan ON ( jan.txt = fev.txt )
WHERE
    jan.id IS NULL;
```

Saída:

```
| id |   txt |
|----|-------|
|  4 | SIGMA |
|  5 | OMEGA |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/557e04/1

Answer (score 0):

Pesquise pelo operador EXCEPT.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html

"EXCEPT returns all rows that are in the result of query1 but not in the result of query2. (This is sometimes called the difference between two queries.) Again, duplicates are eliminated unless EXCEPT ALL is used."